# Как экранировать вывод?

Tags: php, html, sql, веб-программирование

У меня всегда большие проблемы с экранированием, потому-что глаза просто ломаются когда пытаюсь все анкспектед прочекать
вот есть код:

```
while ($row_core = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_core,SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) 
{
        $gp++;

        echo '<input type="checkbox" name ="group-'<?php echo $gp; ?>"  >
        <label for="<?php echo $gp; ?>">

        $sql_s_core = "SELECT nameM FROM dbo.menu WHERE head_id=0";
        $result_core = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

}
```

Это кусок меню, а именно чек бокс, суть  в том, что значения лэйбла для него вытаскаваются из БД в цикле, у чекбокса и лэйбла есть id которые должны быть для каждого нового чек бокса новыми, новый пункт меню. Как мне это правильно экранировать? В цикле сделал переменую `$gp` которая за каждый круг цикла становится +1, затем ее значение выводится в id эллемента.

Comment: Сам подход неочень , дергать базу каждый раз в цикле, а если в цикле 1000 значений , 1000 запросов? надо полюбому джойнить табличку.

Comment: Что именно нужно  экранировать? Вывод какой переменной?

Comment: @koks_rs
вывод переменной gp в name ="group-$gp" id="group-$dp"

Comment: А зачем там(внутри `echo`) вообще разрыв `php` тэгов то? XZibit передает пламенный примет: _Я вставил разрыв пхп в эхо, чтоб ты смог эхать пока эхаешь!_

Comment: @SLy_huh, а попробуйте вместо троллинга в след раз объяснить  почему это не корректно?

Comment: @koks_rs мне кажется следует различать такие понятия как "шутка" и "троллинг". Я думаю, что вопрос сам на себя отвечает, _зачем разрыв тэгов и`echo` внутри `echo`_, нет?

Comment: @SLy_huh,  нет, я почему-то уверен что для того кто задал этот вопрос, такая "шутка" не содержит ответа на его вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы спутали понятия. Экранирование :

```
echo "Экранирование символов делается \"Так\".";
// Выдаст : Экранирование символов делается "Так".
```

Вам нужно просто вставить переменную в строку:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='group-{$gp}'>";
// Выдаст : <input type='checkbox' name='group-1'>
```

Так тоже сработает, результат тот-же

```
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='group-$gp'>";
```

Фигурные скобки нужны для вывода более сложных выражений вроде доступа к элементу массива :

```
$arr = array("value" => "foo");
echo "это {$arr['value']} !";
// Выдаст: это foo !
```

Comment: спасибо большое, стало ясно теперь

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name ="group-' . $gp . '">';
        echo '<label for="' . $gp . '">';
```

Comment: пожалуйста, давайте более развернутые ответы